# Java inheritance, how to override a method in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I am working on a practice interview question. The problem is to implement a sorted stack using only one more stack for temporary storage.

Description of implementation: I am extending Stack class to implement my SortedStack class. Most methods of SortedStack class are identical to Stack class, so I don't need to implement them. Only the push method is overridden.

In my implementation, I am passing the current stack to push method. My question is: is this the best way to access the existing stack. Can I access stack's contents without passing it to push() method?

**Node.java**

```
public class Node {
    private int key;
    private float value;

    public Node(int key, float value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey() { return key; }
    public void setKey(int key) { this.key = key; }

    public float getValue() { return value; }
    public void setValue(float value) { this.value = value; }
}
```

**SortedStack.java**

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class SortedStack extends Stack {

    public SortedStack() {
        super();
    }

    public void push(Stack<Node> mainStack, Node newNode) {
        Stack<Node> tempStack = new Stack<Node>();

        while (!mainStack.isEmpty()) {
            if (mainStack.peek().getKey() > newNode.getKey()) {
                tempStack.push(mainStack.pop());
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

        mainStack.push(newNode);

        while (!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
            mainStack.push(tempStack.pop());
        }
    }

}
```

**SortedStackApp.java**

```
public class SortedStackApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SortedStack stack = new SortedStack();

        stack.push(stack, new Node(10, 1.1f));
        stack.push(stack, new Node(80, 1.8f));
        stack.push(stack, new Node(50, 1.5f));
        stack.push(stack, new Node(90, 1.9f));
        stack.push(stack, new Node(20, 1.2f));
        stack.push(stack, new Node(30, 1.3f));

        Node node = null;

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            node = (Node) stack.pop();
            System.out.printf("(%d, %3.1f) ", node.getKey(), node.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Stack is the java.util.Stack as described at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Comment: This is not a good implementation, because you are **overloading** `push()` rather than overriding it. A user using your stack will still use the `push` with one parameter. Please review overloading vs. overriding.

Comment: I would have SortedStack **use** a Stack.  Yes, you have to create all the methods from Stack, but you have access to the entire Stack, as well as modifying the push method as you wish.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, agreed overriding is better than overloading. Especially since I am using all other methods from Stack unchanged. Your comment has helped in rephrasing my question better. My original question rephrased is: can I access stack's contents without passing it to push() method.

Comment: So I suggest you edit your question and change it accordingly. I also suggest adding the `Stack` class itself as it's hard to guess what methods you are inheriting etc.

Comment: @RealSkeptic. I have updated the question to reflect changes you suggested. I will also update SortedStack and SortedStackApp so Node is passed to push() method instead of key and value.

Comment: Why are you passing `stack` in your push method (`mainStack`)?

Comment: @NullUserException. In fact that is the question I am asking. How can I access the stack in the SortedStack class without having to pass it to push method.

Comment: `super` or `this`, depending on what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, if you are extending `java.util.Stack`, you should provide a base type for it. This is wrong:

```
public class SortedStack extends Stack {...}
```

In this case, `Stack` is a **raw type**. Raw types should only be used with legacy code, as you lose the type safety. Instead, you should use:

```
public class SortedStack extends Stack<Node> {...}
```

Doing so will automatically make your stack accept only `Node` elements.

As I said in the comments, you should be **overriding** the `push` method, not overloading it. This means that it has to have exactly the same parameters as the parent class's `push` method. Thus, it should only take a `Node` parameter, and that's it. Mark the method with the `@Override` annotation to make sure that you are really overriding it and not overloading. The compiler will issue an error if you have extra parameters or incompatible parameter types.

You'll note, once you do that, that you have to change the declaration of the method to also return `Node`, as this is how `push` is declared in `java.util.Stack`.

So your method should be:

```
@Override
public Node push(Node n) {
   ...
}
```

And you should call it from your `main` using:

```
stack.push( new Node( 10, 1.1f ) );
```

Since you have declared it properly with the type, you won't need to cast the result of `pop` to `Node`:

```
node = stack.pop(); // No need for (Node)
```

---

Now that we have a properly typed class, well, your item **is** the stack. This is what inheritance actually means: "This class that I am writing now is a `Stack` and has all the `Stack` methods, and stores all the `Stack` data, I'm just changing some of its behavior."

So to access the "main" stack it simply needs to access **itself**. For example, you while loop should be:

```
    while (!this.empty()) {
        if (this.peek().getKey() > n.getKey()) {
            tempStack.push(this.pop());
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

And really, you can also get rid of the `this` because there is no ambiguity. Calling `empty()` is the same as calling `this.empty()` (you used `isEmpty()` in your code but `java.util.Stack` has only `empty()`).

So it really should be:

```
    while (!empty() && peek().getKey() > n.getKey() ) {
        tempStack.push(pop());
    }
```

(I improved your loop a bit, there was no need for the extra `if`).

However, beware of using `this.push()` or just `push()` to get your main stack. You can use `super.push()` instead. That way it will use the original behavior to `push` the item into the actual stack:

```
    super.push(n); // Don't use new Node() here. Push the node you were given.

    while (!tempStack.empty()) {
        super.push(tempStack.pop());
    }
```

If you don't do this, you will be calling the same `push` you are writing right now recursively. This will not be what you wanted - you wanted a "plain" push to be used internally.

Remember to return the `Node` you inserted once you are done.

Another option would be to not extend `Stack` but re-implement all the methods and have an internal stack. Look up "Composition vs. Inheritance" to decide which is better.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. In my mind, I was thinking using 'this' anywhere inside SortedStack would refer to an object of type Node, not the Stack itself. Your detailed explanation covered every question that I had and in fact anticipated any further questions I would have had. You mentioned Composition vs Inheritance. I will certainly look it up and learn about relative pros&cons. In my original implementation, my SortedSort did not extend Stack but used an internal stack. I felt using inheritance would be a learning experience for me and it certainly was!

Answer (score -1):

This is the only way to do it. You are unable to access direct data, as it is stored in the Node as a private which is then sent to the Stack